# How to access localhost on Virtualbox host machine

Tags: virtualbox, lamp, localhost

I created a virtual machine on Virtualbox with Ubuntu 12.04 only to install a LAMP solution and use it with my host machine, but I can't access the localhost using the ip (10.0.2.15) in the browser .

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Run ifconfig | grep inet on VM and browse using that ip from your Host.

Comment: It gives me this : "inet end.: 10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Masc:255.255.255.0, endereço inet6: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0b:7fee/64 Escopo:Link" but the 10.0.2.15 don't work, and ping to this ip only results on a 100% lost packages.

Comment: From your VM, can you access 10.0.2.15? Does UFW enable? Did you allow port?

Comment: This is something I didn't have tested actually (only localhost). But yes it works perfectly on the VM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you should change the Network adapater to Bridged (It seems you are choosing NAT)

[image]

Then you can give an ip to your guest machine other than `10.0.2.15` (or you can leave it if you want)

then open a browser from your host machine and type: *ip-address-of-your-guest-machine/...*

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, when I select Bridged Adapter I loose the connection, and even after restarting (when Virtualbox doesn't give me any error), I can't connect at all (on the guest machine) to the network. How can I solved this ?

Comment: are you sure that you give an ip of same range of your network?!

Comment: be sure to give ip similar to your host with same dns and same gateway

Comment: I can't enable my virtual machine with the Bridged Adapter because it crashes and keep asking be about the vboxdrv (that is started), when I switch to NAT it loads without any problem. I will try to change from NAT to Bridged and then make they use the same ip to see if it works.

Comment: Sorry my fault ! I messed up with the modules :S... But now I activated normally and everything is working :D (I just need to remember to not mess manually with the modules like I do on Arch Linux). Thank you very much for you help :D

Comment: You are welcome but please mark as answer to help others later